# Change the url as the query var in htaccess wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a url like http://exmple.com/company/?n=Brunswick%20&%20Sons.

First, i have read this post. https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever

But i cant understand rewrite rule easily. I want the query as like http://exmple.com/company/Brunswick%20&%20Sons.

Can anyone help to understand this thing do this work 100%.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code in root/.htaccess:

```
  RewriteEngine On

#1)Redirect from http://example.com/company/?q=foo
#to http://example.com/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /company/\?n=(.+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [B,NC,L,R]
#first round of rewriting ends here


 #2) in this round , mod_rewrite will
 #internally map http://example.com/foo to
#http://example.com/company/?n=foo.
#the following 2 conditions check if the /foo is an existent directory or file, skip the rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /company/?n=$1 [B,NC,L]
```

Comment: In first one, You said RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /company/\?n=(.+)\s [NC] is condition for changing from http://example.com/company/?q=foo to http://example.com/foo. But i want http://example.com/company/foo. So should i use this one. %{THE_REQUEST} /\?n=(.+)\s [NC] and what is the Rewrite rule for this.

Comment: I got the solution. Thank you.